# Error while loading user-defined function in QGIS

Tags: error, expression, qgis-3

Why does an error occur when I load a user-defined function in QGIS 3.12.2?

The expression:

```py
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom'):
def getHeight(layId, itemId, feature, parent):
    layout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName(layId)
    item = layout.itemById(itemId)
    #item.refreshItemSize()
    return item.rect().height()
```

The error message:

```py
2020-05-16T21:01:46 WARNING Пользовательское выражение getLayoutByName не действительно
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA1/QGIS31.12/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\user.py", line 46, in load_user_expressions
import("expressions.{0}".format(name), locals(), globals())
File "C:/PROGRA1/QGIS31.12/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 744, in _import
mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
File "C:/Users/genf/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python\expressions\getLayoutByName.py", line 1, in
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
NameError: name 'qgsfunction' is not defined

2020-05-16T21:01:46 WARNING Пользовательское выражение getTop не действительно
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PROGRA1/QGIS31.12/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\user.py", line 46, in load_user_expressions
import("expressions.{0}".format(name), locals(), globals())
File "C:/PROGRA1/QGIS31.12/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 744, in _import
mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
File "C:/Users/genf/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python\expressions\getTop.py", line 1, in
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
NameError: name 'qgsfunction' is not defined
```

Comment: please add the code of your function

Comment: Have you imported `qgsfunction`? e.g. `from qgis.utils import qgsfunction`

Answer (score 1):

```
NameError: name 'qgsfunction' is not defined
```

Is likely because you have not imported `qgsfunction`.  Try:

```
from qgis.utils import qgsfunction

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom'):
def getHeight(layId, itemId, feature, parent):
    layout = QgsProject.instance().layoutManager().layoutByName(layId)
    item = layout.itemById(itemId)
    #item.refreshItemSize()
    return item.rect().height()
```